# Testing on Real device

Tags: android

If i use the .apk file that is in the bin directory in the project in the workspace instead of generating the .apk by exporting the project does it make difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk file in the bin is signed using the debug key, which loses the benefit of signing your App. Your App should be signed using your own key (which is specified when you export the project) which kind of uniquely identify your Apps and protects (or tries to protect) your Apps from having someone alter your App and republish it. Also, when you upload an update for your App, it must be signed with the same key as the original App, so make sure to keep this key safe.

Comment: If i update my project does my apk that i have make it using export method updated automatically or do i need to create a new apk key??

Comment: The signing process happens during the export, if you need to update an App already on Google Play, you must use the same key file that you used when you exported the first version. Otherwise, it does not matter if you use same license for all Apps or one license per App. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: If you are just testing (either on emulator or on device) it does not matter if you use the apk in the bin directory or you export. Signing is only important in publishing only. Sorry if I may have confused you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apk from the bin folder while debugging, but when publishing the app, you must export a signed apk, or sign the one from the bin folder manually.

However, an easier method would be to directly debug on a hardware device from eclipse, as this gives you access to various tools like the adb and LogCat, See [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) link for details.

Comment: Of course those tools also work from the command line.  What eclipse  gives you is (possibly) one-click startup, and if you choose to use it, java source-level debugging.

Comment: His question mentioned that the apk was in the workspace, so I assumed he was using Eclipse, in which case he might as well use the features given.

Comment: Even when using eclipse, there are lots of reasons to use the command line tools directly as well - stability, custom filtering, additional adb commands.  If you change package signatures, eclipse will even tell you that you have to remove the old package from the command line (and give you the command)